# Calculate different value from MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

What I have in MySQL table

```
|seller |product |weight |quantity|
|---------------------------------|
|Jacob  |Mobile  | 500g  |   2    |
|John   |Laptop  | 3500g |   1    |
|Kiki   |Charger | 1000g |        |
|Dani   |Keyboard| 1500g |   3    |
```

If one customer orders x2 items from Jacob seller, x1 item from John, and x3 from Dani,
then this customer now ordered 6 items with total 9,000 gram weight from 3 sellers.

```
2 items from jacob = 500 x 2
1 item from John = 3500 x 1 
3 items from Dani = 1500 x 3
```

**I want to put these values in php variable**

```
$jacob_items_weight = 500 x 2;
$John_items_weight = 3500 x 1;
$Dani_items_weight = 1500 x 3;
$total_weight_customer_have = 9000;
```

I already tried using for each loop but I can get only the total weight value, but I want all the above variables so I can use them separately.

The main Aim is to calculate `$shipping_price`

```
<?php
 if($pro_weight <= 500){
    $shipping_price = 10;
 }else if($pro_weight <= 1000){
    $shipping_price = 15;
 }else if($pro_weight <= 2000){
    $shipping_price = 25;
 }else if($pro_weight <= 3000){
    $shipping_price = 35;
 }else if($pro_weight <= 4000){
    $shipping_price = 45;
 }else if($pro_weight <= 5000){
    $shipping_price = 55;
 }else if($pro_weight <= 6000){
    $shipping_price = 62.5;
 }else if($pro_weight <= 7000){
    $shipping_price = 70;
 }else if($pro_weight <= 8000){
    $shipping_price = 77.5;
 }else if($pro_weight <= 9000){
    $shipping_price = 95;
 }else if($pro_weight <= 10000){
    $shipping_price = 100;
 }else{
   $shipping_price = 'Sorry We can\'t deliver over 10 KGs';
  }
 ?>
```

Now

```
`$shipping_price` of `$jacob_items_weight` (500x 2) is 15 USD.

`$shipping_price` of `$John_items_weight` (3500x 1) is 45 USD.

`$shipping_price` of `$Dani_items_weight ` (1500x 3) is 55 USD.
```

Now finally I want `15  + 45 + 55 = 115 USD.`

```
  $first_seller_shipping_price = 15; 

  $second_seller_shipping_price = 15; 

  $third_seller_shipping_price = 15;

  $total_shipping_price = 155;
```

If you get my point if I try to calculate for all 9000 g of items the shipping price will be 95 USD. But due difference in the sellers I have to calculate differently then add them to be 115 like the above. so now instead of 95 the shipping will be 115 USD in total.

How can I achieve this goal?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is the quantity in the table?

Comment: Use an associative array with each seller name as the keys, not different variables.

Comment: Do you really store the number with its unit together? `500g`?

Comment: @anan Is there any to put the values in individual variables ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$weights = [];
$total_weight = 0;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc) {
    $item_weight = $row['quantity'] * $row['weight'];
    $total_weight += $item_weight;
    if (isset($weights[$row['seller']])) {
        $weights[$row['seller']] += $item_weight;
    } else {
        $weights[$row['seller']] = $item_weight;
    }
}
echo "Total weight = $total_weight<br>";
print_r($weights);
```

Comment: Your answer is what I'm looking for, But there is one issue that I can't resolve, that is  print_r($weights); excutes all sellers with their own weight, it is cool, But I want excute them all out in variable.  thank you for your help.

Comment: It makes no sense to have separate variables, because the seller names could be anything -- how would you refer to the variables later in the code? Just use the associative array.

Comment: thank you for your help again but now I tried to update the question to be clear as much as possible. If you get my idea please help me.

Comment: What is `$pro_weight`?

Comment: Sorry I just copied from my main  code But  $pro_weight could be any of the sellers item weight that foreach through all selllers item weight

Comment: So change it to `$weights['pro']`

Comment: Sorry I can't get it what is the pro inside the brackets=> $weights['pro'] and I can I add all the shipping price for all and get one total value? sorry for too many questions?

Comment: It's the seller name from the database. You can make another associative array with all the sellers' shipping costs.

Comment: `foreach ($weights as $seller => $weight) { if ($weight <= 500) { $shipping_price = 10; } ...`

Comment: I can't Thank enough for your great help, after I add this foreach ($weights as $seller => $weight) it works very well, Thank you so much.